# MonthCalendar Dates are not changing to Bold

Tags: mysql, vb.net, monthcalendar

Hi i am having problems highlighting or making my selected date bold. Example when i add event to that date it should be bold so i will know that there are entries inside the date. But It's not working and i dont know what's wrong.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    mydbcon = New MySqlConnection
    mydbcon.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=jared;password=jared;database=database"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        mydbcon.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "Insert into database.calendar (eventname,EventDate,Time,Description) Values ('" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & Form4.MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start & "','" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem & "','" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, mydbcon)
        reader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        MessageBox.Show("Event Succesfully Saved")
        mydbcon.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        mydbcon.Dispose()


        Try
            mydbcon.Open()
            Dim eventdate As String
            eventdate = "SELECT * FROM database.calendar Where EventDate = '" & Form4.MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start & "'"
            reader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

            If reader.HasRows = True Then
                While reader.Read
                    eventdate = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("EventDate")).ToShortDateString
                    Form4.MonthCalendar1.AddBoldedDate(CDate(eventdate))
                End While
                reader.Close()
                Form4.MonthCalendar1.UpdateBoldedDates()
            End If
            mydbcon.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            mydbcon.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Are you able to get rows from the database? The query as written will only return rows that exactly match a single date.

Comment: @JerryM I think i can get the rows. If my query only returns the match date then how could i possible do what i want to do. please help

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the line 'Form4.MonthCalendar1.AddBoldedDate(CDate(eventdate))'. If it doesn't break, you're not getting any rows. If you're not getting rows, then the query is wrong. If you do get rows, then I don't see where the problem is since the code looks good otherwise.

Comment: @JerryM Bro i get an missingmemberexcempttion at the eventdate=reader.getvalue line how do i fix? thanks

Comment: Try Clean and Build to see what's missing. I've also noticed that in the second Try block the statement `eventdate = "SELECT * FROM database.calendar` isn't functional (the value is set but not used) And the `COMMAND` isn't modified from the first try. Is this what you intended?

Comment: @JerryM How can i used the values i set on eventdate? And is there a better or easier way bolding my dates? I am quite new to programming so please teach me. Appreciated it bro thanks